# How can i substring of path based on my requirement?

Tags: java, filepath

```
String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
```

means i'm getting root value as `C:\Users\vinay\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FileAnalog\build\web\`

but i need the root value output only till `C:\Users\vinay\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FileAnalog\`
how can i write new string root1 to get the root till FileAnalog.Thanks for help.

Comment: I dont know how to do this,can you guide me please

Comment: String root2 = root.substring(0, root.indexOf("build"));  i did this but not working

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html -- `split()`?

Answer (score 0):

String root2 = root.substring(0, root.indexOf("build"));

Its working fine

Comment: I hope you have not asked this question to answer it, cos thats not encoraged here. else we are super cool

Comment: It wasn't working as per your comment. Correct me if i am wrong